# Unable to use TorchAudio

Tags: python, windows, pip, torchaudio

Good morning, for some reason I cannot get TorchAudio to be used after installing.

I've tried both:

`pip3 install torchaudio`

`conda install torchaudio`

and a few other options but, I always get the error:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchaudio'".

Yet this shows up in the `pip list`.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue like this?

Comment: Is this the only module you are unable to use after installing, or is this just an issue of you not knowing, in general, how to install python modules to the environment you're running scripts in?

Comment: This is the only module that has been behaving this way and haven't had issues with the hundreds of modules i've tried in the past.

Comment: Have you checked that the python interpreter that is running your code is the one you are expecting and that `pip3 install` or `conda install` installed to?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

conda install -c pytorch torchaudio